# Node coffeescript class files and inheritance

Tags: node.js, inheritance, coffeescript

I have 2 class files:

foo.coffee: `class Foo`

bar.coffee: `class Bar extends Foo`

How do I define these classes so they are globally available?  I get the error in `Bar` that `Foo` is not defined.

I have an index.js file that I call `node` on to run the scripts.  Here is the contents of index.js, I most likely did this wrong also:

```
exports.Foo = require("./foo")
exports.Bar = require("/bar")
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

foo.coffee:

```
class Foo
  // ...

module.exports = Foo
```

bar.coffee:

```
Foo = require "./foo"

class Bar extends Foo
  // ...

module.exports = Bar
```

index.coffee:

```
exports.Foo = require "./foo"
exports.Bar = require "./bar"
```

**UPDATE:** You also need to run `.coffee` files with `coffee`, unless you compile them first.

**UPDATE 2:** How you structure your models is up to you. I like the pattern above (where simple modules export just a function -- that's when you need to assign to `module.exports` because you can't simply assign to `exports`) but others prefer a structure like this:

foo.coffee:

```
class Foo
  // ...

exports.Foo = Foo
```

bar.coffee:

```
Foo = require("./foo").Foo

class Bar extends Foo
  // ...

exports.Bar = Bar
```

index.coffee:

```
exports.Foo = require("./foo").Foo
exports.Bar = require("./bar").Bar
```

Where each module exports an object with one or more properties.

Comment: I wanted to chime in and say that I agree with Linus and how a module should export just the class. Of course, there are some exceptions, but overall it's good practice.

Comment: (Apologies for OT!) — @Linus: Can you recommend an approach to use the same technique on the client side? RequireJS (seems to like a lot of overhead)?

Comment: @polarblau: Sure, I use [stitch](https://github.com/sstephenson/stitch) which works very well for me. Small, lightweight and gives you `require` on the client.

Answer (score 3):

You can also write:

```
class @MyClass
  [...]

{MyClassName} = require './myclassFile'
myClass = new MyClassName
```